# RavenDB SelectMany not supported

Tags: linq, ravendb

I am trying to find one or more documents in RavenDB based on the values of a child collection.

I have the following classes

```
public class GoldenDocument
{
    public GoldenDocument()
    {
        LinkedDocuments = new List<LinkedDocument>();
        MergeMatchFields = new List<MergeMatchField>();
    }

    public string Id { get; set; }
    public Guid SourceRowId { get; set; }
    public List<MergeMatchField> MergeMatchFields { get; set; }
    public List<LinkedDocument> LinkedDocuments { get; set; }
}
```

And the class that is in the collection `MergeMatchFields`

```
public class MergeMatchField
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public Guid OriginId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public MatchType MatchType { get; set; }
    public double MatchPerc { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

In a `List<MergeFields> mergeFields` collection I have values that is not stored in RavenDB yet. Values are compared to values in a RavenDB document for find if it is a possible match by executing the following query:

```
using (var session = documentStore.OpenSession())
{
    var docs = from gd in session.Query<GoldenDocument>()
                from mf in gd.MergeMatchFields
                from tf in mergeFields
                where mf.Name == tf.Name 
                && JaroWinklerCalculator.jaroWinkler(mf.Value, tf.Value) > .90d 
                && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(mf.Value)
                select gd;
}
```

I understand that ravenDB does not support `SelectMany()` so how would I go about getting the results from the Document store?

Answer (score 1):

Create an index for this that would output the values you want to query on.
Note that you can't just execute arbitrary code the way you do here: `JaroWinklerCalculator.jaroWinkler(mf.Value, tf.Value) > .90d`

But you can use fuzzy queries, and they will do the same.

Comment: Thanks Ayende, with Fuzzy Queries I assume you mean that RavenDB has built in support for JaroWinkler and/or Levenshtein or one of those algorithms?